# How do we read the last line of a csv file using filehelper class and then ignore the last line

Tags: c#, filehelpers

How do we read the last line of a csv file using filehelper class and then ignore the last line. Or How do i ignore last line from csv file using filehelper then get the last line to a variable

Please help

Comment: Read the last line and then ignore it - how is that different from doing nothing at all? Please elaborate.

Comment: You need to rephrase that question, be more specific, show your code, what you tried. You want to read the last line but then ignore it? What's the point?

Comment: Welcome to SO! `How do we read the last line of a csv file using filehelper class and then ignore the last line`, could you please update your post to include what you have tried, what `filehelper` class is, expected outcome and a case for us to replicate to help you further.

Answer (score 2):

More I read your question more I get confused about what you're asking. But from what I understood, following should solve your problem.

You can use `[IgnoreLast(1)]` attribute for this. Number in the attribute indicates how many lines to skip.

There is also an `[IgnoreFirst(1)]` attribute which works the same way.

If you want to get first or last line then you can use `HeaderText` or `FooterText` properties of `FileHelperEngine` class.

Comment: thank you. Thats exactly what i am lokking for. Also how do we get the ignored line after the read.

Comment: @SajiSolomen What do you mean read ignored line after the read? Do you want to read that line as well? Why ignore it then? Also, if this answers it your question then please accept the answer.